# Identify element by class name

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<input class="js-search-submitBtn Button Button--search" type="submit" value="Search">
```

How to identity element by selenium webdriver using `By.className(className)`

I tried by using :

```
HH.findElement(By.className("js-search-submitBtn Button Button--search")).click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called compound class and you cannot use that with `selenium`. Instead convert that to css selector

```
.js-search-submitBtn.Button.Button--search
```

Implementation:

```
HH.findElement(By.cssSelector(".js-search-submitBtn.Button.Button--search")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, `class="js-search-submitBtn Button Button--search"` is a **space separated list** of classes. You can use something like: `By.className(js-search-submitBtn)`.